# Python not installing on windows 11

Tags: python

I cant install python on my `windows 11`

it says `Could not access network location_\.`
how do I fix it?

I tried disabling the windows firewall and my antivirus but it didn't help.

I tried running as administrator too.

I even tried to download python from pycharm but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide more information in order to solve the issue.

Comment: Looks like registry issue i encountered few years back, Please check
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/error-1606could-not-access-network-location-in32/609b1782-35e7-4ebb-9957-11da58cb1ba1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which python version / distribution you're trying to install, but I was having issues installing Winpython64-3.7.10.0PyPy.  After the file extraction would complete the files simply wouldn't be there.

I reattempted installation with Winpython64-3.9.5.0 and it worked like a charm.  I installed to the C: directory.